Watermark RTL text appears incorrect
I am using Itext 5 and I am trying to add non removable watermark text as follows, but the issue is that the RTL text appears incorrectly:
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(byteArray);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);

BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, BaseFont.WINANSI, false);
String watermarkText = "مسودة";

int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
    Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i);

    // get handle for existing page content
    PdfImportedPage pageContent = stamper.getImportedPage(reader, i);
    // store that content as form XObject
    stamper.getWriter().addToBody(pageContent.getFormXObject(stamper.getWriter().getCompressionLevel()), pageContent.getIndirectReference());
    pageContent.setCopied();
    // reset page content
    reader.getPageN(i).put(PdfName.CONTENTS, null);

    // create pattern with former page content
    PdfPatternPainter bodyPainter = stamper.getOverContent(i).createPattern(pageSize.getWidth(),
            pageSize.getHeight());
    bodyPainter.addTemplate(pageContent, 0, 0);

    // add watermark to pattern
    PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
    state.setFillOpacity(0.3f);
    bodyPainter.saveState();
    bodyPainter.setGState(state);
    for (float x = 70f; x < pageSize.getWidth(); x += 100) {
        for (float y = 90; y < pageSize.getHeight(); y += 100) {
            bodyPainter.beginText();
            bodyPainter.setTextRenderingMode(PdfPatternPainter.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL);
            bodyPainter.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 13);
            bodyPainter.showTextAlignedKerned(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, watermarkText, x, y, 45f);
            bodyPainter.endText();
        }
    }
    bodyPainter.restoreState();

    // create new page content
    PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getUnderContent(i);
    // add pseudo-content
    canvas.beginText();
    canvas.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 13);
    canvas.showTextAlignedKerned(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, "        ", 0, 0, 45f);
    canvas.endText();
    // fill with pattern holding former page content
    canvas.setColorFill(new PatternColor(bodyPainter));
    canvas.rectangle(pageSize.getLeft(), pageSize.getBottom(), pageSize.getWidth(),
            pageSize.getHeight());
    canvas.fill();
}

stamper.close();
reader.close();
byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

The watermark appears incorrectly as follows:

How can I fix this issue?

If I recall correctly, text 5 only has limited support for RTL scripts,  in particular if only world in specific contexts.

@mkl,is there is any workaround to write the RTL watermark text correctly ?

Actually I have never had to make RTL scripts work, so I have no hands-on experience. If I recall correctly, though, RTL kind of works in PdfPTable cells and some ColumnText use cases, so you might want to try playing around with them. Alternatively consider drawing the text onto a bitmap image and painting that image in the pattern you use.

but If use PdfPTable  and ColumnText  the text can be removed then ?

"but If use PdfPTable and ColumnText the text can be removed then ?" - You obviously still need to use PdfPTable / ColumnText with the PdfPatternPainter. And the watermark created by the code you pasted also can be removed; it's just not that obvious in most editors how to do that.

so there is no solution at all to make watermark not removable ?

You can flatten the watermarked PDF pages into a bitmap each and build a PDF only containing them. But even for that there are some reasonably good image processing tools to remove such watermarks.

@mkl, I have different question, after applying the watermark solution above code, I cannot copy the pdf text content anymore, is there's any way to make the original pdf text content can be copied ?

No. The idea of the solution above is to put both the original page content and the watermark into a pattern with which the page is then filled. Ways to edit patterns aren't obvious in most PDF editors, so with them you naively can only remove the whole pattern, i.e. when removing the watermark you remove everything. Unfortunately not only editing patterns is not supported, also text extraction from them. Thus, not being able to copy&paste from such PDFs is a side effect of this way of applying watermarks.

I was able to fix it as follows:
for (float x = xAxis; x < pageSize.getWidth(); x += height + 100) {
                    for (float y = yAxis; y < pageSize.getHeight(); y += height + 100) {

                        if (isRTL) {
                            ColumnText.showTextAligned(bodyPainter, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, rtlPhrase, x, y, 45f,
                                    PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL, ColumnText.DIGITS_AN2EN);
                        } else {
                            bodyPainter.beginText();
                            bodyPainter.setTextRenderingMode(PdfPatternPainter.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL);
                            bodyPainter.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 13);
                            bodyPainter.showTextAlignedKerned(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, watermarkText, x, y, 45f);
                            bodyPainter.endText();
                        }

                    }
                }

